# Reading JSON files from Hadoop with Spark

Tags: java, json, hadoop, apache-spark

I have several JSON files (zipped with .gz format) in some HDFS directories in a tree like:

```
/master/dir1/file1.gz
       /dir2/file2.gz
       /dir3/file3.gz
       ...
```

I need to read those files from the path /master/ and join them into a RDD with Spark in Java. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]
If

```
JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://master/dir*/file*");
```

doesn't work, another way is to list the files and union

```
fileSystem.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://master/dir*"))
  .filter(d -> d.isDirectory())
  .map(p -> sc.textFile(p.getPath()))
  .reduce((a, b) -> a.unionAll(b))
```

Comment: It doesn't work because in Spark, Hadoop doesn't go recursively through directories.